# Killing process with python

Tags: python, linux, process

I'm trying to kill recent processes that start AFTER my program starts, after a condition, the program will keep running continuously, but it has only killed the processes that started BEFORE the program ran, if I run it first, and then open something nothing happens, can anyone help me? I've tried several things and I end up in the same place, thank you very much. (OS = LINUX) (sorry for bad english, i'm still learning)

```py
p = psutil.pids()

for x in p:
       s = psutil.Process(x)
       tempo_processos = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s.create_time()).strftime("%H%M%S")
       if int(time.strftime("%H%M%S")) - int(tempo_processos) < 500:  #get the current time taking the time that the process was started to get the shortest possible time
            if s.name() == 'python3':
               pass
            else:
              os.popen(f"kill -9 {x}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`psutil.pids` gets the PIDs of the processes running when the code is executing, so any processes started after you code started wouldn't be returned by `psutil.pids` and, therefore, can't be killed.

You can try something like this:

```py
while True:
    p = psutil.pids()
    kill processes
    wait(some time)
```